# Dwarf galaxy rotation speed around Andromeda/Mily way

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve, galaxy-clusters

We know that the rotation speed of stars around the center of a galaxy is roughly flat.

But how fast does the dwarf galaxy rotate around the bigger galaxy, say andromeda or milky way?

Do they also rotate at the same speed as the stars in the andromeda galaxy? i.e. for a dwarf galaxy rotating around andromeda, would its speed around the andromeda be around 230km/s?

Comment: Could be a good question for [astronomy.se]